# Extjs 4 how show in store window grid selected row

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs4

I have problem how show the selected row from window into store which is integrated to listview look like this:

```
onSelectBtnSelect:function(oBtn){
     var row = this.getContactsGrid().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].get('first_name');
     var store = Ext.create('Aenis.store.docmgmt.warrants.SelectedWarrants',{});
     store.insert(0,{"contactName":row});
     store.commitChanges();
     var win = oBtn.up('window');
    win.close();
    console.log(store.data);
}
```

after `insert()` or `add()` method when I am doing console.log store data it is not showing me the added element in my lsitview.I need to refresh my listview.I tried `store.reload()` `store.load()` `grid.getStore.loadData`,but all are giving errors.

Comment: You're telling it to create a new store. I don't see anywhere where you attach that store to a view.

Comment: No I have store warrantsStore in begin it is empty and then I am selecting the record and pressing Select then that record should go to store should be add, adding is being but it is not showing, that is problem .yes I have attached view everything works fine, merely that moment I need, when window is closed I can get the selected record and I can insert to my store but I can't to show that record in view.

Answer (score 0):

Try using store.sync() instead of store.commitChanges(), hopefully that should work!!

Baz